# GNU Make rule not detecting .o files from dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, gnu-make

I'm having issues with rule B in my Makefile. I would like to be able to call `make B` to compile my project, but I get a large error message because it doesn't detect the .o files generated by the dependencies. However, it is able to detect the .o files from the first call when I call it again, and it works fine.

I tried printing the .o files with `make say` while in `make B`, and it printed all the files I expected it to. But when I ran the inline version of `make say` right below, it printed nothing, suggesting to me that somehow it is not detecting the .o files in the context of the rule.

Additionally, calling `make A` after cleaning results in success, but I feel this defeats the point of having dependencies in the first place.

```
GPP = g++
VER = -std=c++17

A: Profile.o AllProfiles
    make B

B: Profile.o AllProfiles
    make say               # Prints all .o files
    echo $(wildcard ./*.o) # Prints nothing
    $(GPP) -o ProfileList $(wildcard ./*.o) ProfileList.cpp $(VER)

AllProfiles:
    $(GPP) -c $(wildcard src/profiles/*.cpp) $(VER)

Profile.o: Profile.cpp
    $(GPP) -c Profile.cpp $(VER)

say:
    echo $(wildcard ./*.o)
```

Comment: Can you add the source tree to your post? I see a possible error in AllProfiles creating .o-files in src/profiles directory, and then try read the .o-files from current working directory. Don't take this the wrong way but this makefile look unsalvagable; there are more flaws than lines. With the source tree I could wrap something up in no time.